# How to make a checkbox with rearranging capability in ASPNET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist, asp-usercontrols

I've got a requirement that needs a checkbox with rearranging capability in ASPNET MVC.

**The main purpose is to know which checkbox users selected and allow them to rearrange the checkbox item order as they want.**

My Question is, do there any existing control like this available in mvc(or jquery)? If no, do there any better UI control to fulfill my purpose?

I found the similar question with no appropriate answer.
[listbox with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673883/listbox-with-checkboxes)

I beg for your response. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use the **normal checkbox** with the jQuery-UI [**Sortable**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)?

```
<ul id="sortable" class='ckb-list'>
  <li><input id="chb-1" type="checkbox" value="1"/> Checkbox 1</li>
  <li><input id="chb-2" type="checkbox" value="2"/> Checkbox 2</li>
  <li><input id="chb-3" type="checkbox" value="3"/> Checkbox 3</li>
  <li><input id="chb-4" type="checkbox" value="4"/> Checkbox 4</li>
  <li><input id="chb-5" type="checkbox" value="5"/> Checkbox 5</li>
</ul>
```

and then apply

```
$(function() {
  // sortable methods
  $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();

  // retrieve selection list
  $(".btn-save").bind("click", function() {

    var ids = "",
        iBox = 0;

    // foreach input in .ckb-list
    $(".ckb-list li > input").each(function() {

      if($(this).prop("checked")) {
        // it checked, so, we save
        ids += ++iBox + ". " + $(this).attr("id") + "\n";
      }

    });

    alert("the checkboxes selected and sorted are:\n\n" + ids);
  });
});
```

> [Live example in JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/uwiwow/edit)

You can easily convert the `<input id="chb-5" type="checkbox" value="5"/> Checkbox 5` with the razor syntax:

```
@Html.Checkbox("chb-5", Model.CheckBox5Value)
```

---

for persistence all you need to do is write the HTML is the correct order, let's image you have this table:

```
[TblUserOptions] 
UserOption_id
Option_id
Value
Order
```

all you need to do is:

```
<ul id="sortable" class='ckb-list'>
@foreach(var option in Model.TblUserOptions
                            .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
                            .ThenByDescending(x => x.Option_id))
{
    <li>@Html.Checkbox("chb-" + option.Option_id, option.Value)</li>
}
</ul>
```

You will always have the checkboxes sorted correctly on start, upon save all you need to do is loop through all checkboxes and update the new `Order` value.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!I confess I didn't consider sortable before I asked the question. It's because I want to find a handy control which will persist the change after post-back. To make sortable works with persistence, I may need to use cookie and I remember I once tried it with poor result from different browser...

Comment: I didn't mention the persistence as requirement in my question. So, with an addition requirement, is sortable still a good choice?

Comment: I would always go there, if you need persistence, it's just a matter of writing the correct ordering in your `@foreach` statement when adding the `checkbox`es. Upon `Save` you will save the order in your db, right? so when you load it will have an order, just use that order to create the HTML. There is no need to use cookies.

Comment: I will prefer using cookies as for separated users. The way to make sortable works with are already written in other threads. Simply list it here for reference. Again, thanks for your suggestion!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442232/getting-the-position-of-the-element-in-a-list-when-its-drag-dropped-ui-sortable/2443081#2443081